# Unable to mount SMB shared : mount error(95): Operation not supported

Tags: linux, network-attached-storage, server-message-block

I have created a shared folder in QNAP TS-433. I can mount the SMB share on a Windows client. I am unable to mount the SMB share on Linux (Centos 6.8).

```
mount -t cifs -o ver=3.0,user=test //172.17.134.210/Acronis /mnt/Acronis      
Password: 
mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Comment: it should be vers=3.0, not ver=3.0

Comment: Yes same issue already posted https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144522/mounting-cifs-operation-not-supported

Comment: Setting the vers and sec did not work for me.

Comment: Anything in any logs, which can give clue?